# anchor menu links broken by history.pushState

Tags: javascript

I have a series of menu anchor / hash links on the left hand side of my site. For example

```
<a href="#settings" id="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="">
```

These all work fine.

I have a list of transactions and the button opens the edit form using AJAX, and I use

```
history.pushState({}, null, `/transaction/${id}/edit`);
```

to change the URL and add it to the history stack, and an appropriate popstate to reload the main page when clicking back.

Problem is after the pushState, a click on one of those links will instead reload the page and append the anchor name to the url, so it looks like say /transaction/3354/edit#settings, instead of just opening the dropdown.

Why, please, and how do I stop it happening

Comment: mapping `event.preventDefault()` on those links will likely solve your issue. Without a [mcve] (or any means of testing, really) it's hard to provide a proper answer.

Comment: Yeah I tried a JSFiddle and doing pushState doesn't appear to work as expected so that wasn't any help

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if this is the wrong answer but I changed them from href="#" to href="javascript:;" and it seems to be okay now

Comment: The difference is users will get to see `javascript:;` in the left-bottom corner of the screen when hovering the link instead of current page's URL. If you don't care about that, you're fine. If you do care about it, consider something [along these lines](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/7qehvLu5/) which actually calls `preventDefault()` on `click` event. It could be done with a single listener on the document, instead of one listener on each link, which might be better.

Comment: Or $(document).on('click', '[prevent-default]' (e) =>e.preventDefault() )? 
Either way javascript:; is actually good so people stop middle clicking on the links and opening a copy of the page they're already on in a new tab.

Comment: Yep. It's a perfect case for event delegation but I didn't want to suggest jQuery in case you weren't using it (and doing it vanilla was too much to write - i'm lazy like that).